# Can't cache front page with Boost / Drupal 7

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-boost

I've already configure my Drupal site with Boost.

I have tested and everything works but the front page.

Front page gets cached, but it's being regenerated every pageload.

In Boost configurations I set to cache only listed pages and included two options for this purpose:

inicio

Inicio is a view, which is my frontpage too.

I want a solution, or a workaround. I don't know how to write .htaccess files. If I would know how to do this I will serve the frontpage with my own rule, in case this page exists... or something like that.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried the [boost issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/boost?text=front+page&status=All&priorities=All&categories=All&version=7.x&component=All)?

Comment: In this case that is the last place to go. Right now I want something that works, then I'll try to figure out the best solution. There's more to try and read before going to an issue queue in my opinion. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It should be the first place you go looking when there is a problem with a module.

Comment: Ideally... then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Finally! The answer is this:

```
# Special handling for front page for Apache 2.4
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$
# RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%{ENV:boostpath}/%{HTTP_HOST}/\_%{QUERY_STRING}\.html -s
# RewriteRule .* cache/%{ENV:boostpath}/%{HTTP_HOST}/\_%{QUERY_STRING}\.html [L,T=text/html]
```

You can put this before the .htaccess generated by Boost. Explanations? Here is explained in detail and also the solution: 
https://www.drupal.org/node/2078595#comment-7885027